# How to create Ubercart recurring order with initial $0.00 charge

Tags: ubercart

Is there any way to configure (or trick) Ubercart (7.x-3.4) into accepting an order with initial 0 charge, then subsequently charge non-zero amount?

Goal is to offer a promotion with $0.00 initial charge, then start charging after n-number months or days.

When 0 is set as the cost of the recurring product, Ubercart responds with an erroneous error about no payment method being set up.

[image]

Comment: Hi How you did solve this issue? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at ubercart subscription it offers the ability to create a subscription product with an initial trial period of x days/months and then the amount to charge per day/month following the trial period.